# lxml xpath path/text() cannot return value when '.' is present in scrapy

Tags: xpath, text, scrapy, lxml

the lxml module in scrapy works fine when you try to return something that doesn't contains '.' character using text() function, however when they contains '.' such as '11.14' the query returns '-'. How to solve this?

Here's my code:

```
stock_price = hxs.xpath('//td[@id="gt1"]//text()').extract()
```

The target html looks like this:

```
<td id="gt1" class="txtl green">11.14</td>
```

There are only one gt1 and it always return

```
'-'
```

instead of

```
'11.14'
```

Why? The source URL is http://quote.eastmoney.com/sz000001.html

Tried with couple other data source, as long as the text field contains '.', it will return '-', otherwise everything is fine. Is this a problem with the environment?

Comment: What's the source HTML and URL?

Comment: @paultrmbrth added.

Comment: Why do you have `//text()` instead of `/text()` ?

Comment: @JonClements I've tried both, there's no difference

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the page source, there actually is '-' inside the `td` tag. The final result you see in the browser and can see using developer tools is probably supplied by some JavaScript. So you can either use e.g. Splash to render the page and extract if from the response, or try to explore the page if it's not using some API. When I look through developer tools in Chrome at XHR requests, I can see some call.

Comment: This is exactly right! Do you prefer using splash or will a webdriver work in extracting information?

Comment: @RockyLi I prefer Splash over Selenium and other tools. I has seamless integration with Scrapy via `scrapy-splash` package and from my experience, is more reliable than other tools.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be appearing because you are using //text() and extract() at the same time.

Below code works fine for me in java. change your xpath as below

```
    driver.get("http://quote.eastmoney.com/sz000001.html");
    System.out.println("5");
    String aa=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='gt1']")).getText();
    System.out.println(aa);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm doing this in python, and not using a chromedriver yet. I'll try to use a webdriver from selenium or to see if there's anyway to fetch results from javascript.